# HTML5 video player stutters even after video is loaded

Tags: html5, video, ffmpeg

I am using jwplayer to display videos on my websites but cannot manage to make them running smoothly. They stutter, especially in full screen, although I wait for the video to fully load.

I tried decreasing the video quality from by decreasing the bitrate from 3000k to 1800k (I use ffmpeg to convert the videos). The resolution of the videos is 1280x720 (HD).

Any tips what should I try next? Thanks

== EDIT ==
I tried displaying the same videos forcing jwplayer to use flash instead of html5, and with flash the videos played fine - so the problem is not with the videos themselves.

Comment: ffmpeg command and complete console output is missing. ffmpeg command-line usage questions should be asked at [su] since [so] is limited to programming questions. I voted for migration so please do not cross-post a duplicate question in [su].

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I don't think your comment is really relevant to this specific question.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Which comment and why?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard "*Which comment...*" Um...the only comment that you've posted on this question? "*...and why?*" The question is not about using ffmpeg from the command-line. It's about why his video is stuttering when played through jwplayer on his website.

Comment: @jadarnel27 My comment consisted of two parts (request for ffmpeg info and mention of off-topic). I was unclear as to which you were referring to. As for the stuttering the output was created by ffmpeg (so it is a major factor in this issue) the question uses the [tag:ffmpeg] tag, and "any tips" were requested; which in this case requires the ffmpeg command and complete console output.

Comment: The same on Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

If using Flash, toggle the hardware acceleration to see if it helps:

1. Navigate to the Find Flash Player Version page.
2. Verify that you are in the section titled "Find Flash Player version type and capabilities (Flash developers only)"
3. Right click on your Player version and select "Settings"
4. The Settings dialog will appear, change the tab at the bottom to display (if not already there) and uncheck (or if you'd like to enable, check) the "Enable hardware acceleration" checkbox.
5. Close the dialog and restart your browser.

Source with screenshots: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/891337?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

There might be tons of reasons for your problem; to name the few:

- limited bandwidth
- web server issues (congestion, throttling)
- low memory on client
- bad flash/browser compatibility
- bad video encoding

Each of them requires checking and then the whole question can be asked with more detail - you might even stumble on the solution by going through the checklist.

Comment: I added some details in the question. I don't think the problem is with limited bandwidth or congestion because, as I mentioned, the stuttering continues even when the video is completely downloaded. Bad video encoding also drops, because the videos work fine when played with flash.